# How to select different background image size depending on screen width?

Tags: html, class, url, background

1.How do I change the image size for the background url depending on screen size?

```
<main id="main">


    <section class="uvsbg text-center">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up" style="height:950px;">

    <div class="row" style="background: url('assets/img/contact-bg5.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%; position: relative; height: 850px;">
    
<div class="col-md-12"> <h1 style="color:#fff;text-align:center;margin-top:50px;font-size: 52px;">Contact Us
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do that.

If you are interested in the background being the *full size* of the element, replace the `style` attribute of the `row` div with this: ([Source](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/))

```css
  background: url(assets/img/contact-bg5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Otherwise, you would have to use Javascript to do this if you do not want the background to be the full width of the element. (You can learn a bit about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_get_current_window.asp))

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). Replace the inline-CSS with a class and add the CSS to an external file or using internal CSS.

```html
<main id="main">
  <section class="uvsbg text-center">
    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up" style="height:950px;">
      <div class="row" class="change-bg-image">
        <div class="col-md-12"> <h1 style="color:#fff;text-align:center;margin-top:50px;font-size: 52px;">Contact Us
```

```css
.change-bg-image {
  background: url('assets/img/contact-bg5.jpg'); 
  background-size: 100% 100%; 
  position: relative; 
  height: 850px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .change-bg-image {
    background-size: 50% 50%; 
    position: relative; 
    height: 400px;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use these values as well

> background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit;

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
  .row{
    background-size: 50% 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).